# zend framework 3 - how to disable layout for entire controller

Tags: php, layout, zend-framework3

In Zend Framework 3, is it possible to disable the layout for an entire controller, preferably in the `__construct()` or `onDispatch()` methods?

I know that I can disable the layout for specific actions, for example:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $view = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}
```

However, I would like to disable the layout for all actions in the controller without having to copy and paste the above code in every action.

Answer (score 2):

In your Module class :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()
        ->getEventManager()
        ->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch',
        function ($e) {
            if ($e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller') == '[your controller name in lowercase]') {
                $result = $e->getResult();
                if ($result instanceof \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel) {
                    $result->setTerminal(true);
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception(
                      __METHOD__ . ' expected \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel');
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for a better solution that doesn't get called for every controller. I won't use this, but I would assume it works. Thank you.